# Expression of element in lie algebra, $sp(p,q)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Starting from the definition of Lie groups,

In particular $Sp (p,q)$  : The group of matrices in $Sp(p+q,\mathbb{C})$ which  leave invariant the Hermitian form
      \begin{align}
   &  Z^T K_{p,q} \bar{Z} \qquad i.e., \qquad  g^T K_{p,q} \bar{g} = K_{p,q}, \quad \det(g)=1  \\
    & K_{p,q} = \begin{pmatrix}
     -I_p & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & I_q & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & -I_p & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & I_q
    \end{pmatrix} 
  \end{align}
I want to find the expression of Lie algebra $sp(p,q)$.

---

So let $g = \exp[t Z]$ , $Z \in sp(p,q)$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$ then it satisfies $Z^T K_{p,q} + K_{p,q} \bar{Z}=0$
Thus we have

\begin{align}
  0 =Z^T K_{p,q} + K_{p,q} \bar{Z}= \begin{pmatrix}
- \bar{Z}_{11} - Z_{11}^T & - \bar{Z}_{12} + Z_{21}^T & - \bar{Z}_{13} - Z_{31}^T & - \bar{Z}_{14} + Z_{41}^T \\
 - Z_{12}^T + \bar{Z}_{21} & \bar{Z}_{22} + Z_{22}^T & \bar{Z}_{23} - Z_{32}^T & \bar{Z}_{24} + Z_{42}^T \\
  - Z_{13}^T - \bar{Z}_{31} & Z_{23}^T - \bar{Z}_{32} & - \bar{Z}_{33} - Z_{33}^T & - \bar{Z}_{34} + Z_{43}^T \\
  - Z_{14}^T + \bar{Z}_{41} & Z_{24}^T + \bar{Z}_{42} & - Z_{34}^T + \bar{Z}_{43} & \bar{Z}_{44} + Z_{44}^T
  \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

---

The textbook says the desired form of element of $sp(p,q)$ is 
\begin{align}
  Z = \begin{pmatrix}
Z_{11} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} & Z_{14} \\
\bar{Z}_{12}^T & Z_{22} & Z_{14}^T & Z_{24} \\
-\bar{Z}_{13} & \bar{Z}_{14} & \bar{Z}_{11} & -\bar{Z}_{12} \\
\bar{Z}_{14}^T & -\bar{Z}_{24} & -Z_{12}^T & \bar{Z}_{22} \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
where $Z_{ij}$ are complex matrix. $Z_{11}$ and $Z_{13}$ of order $p$ and $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{14}$ are $p\times q$ matrices. $Z_{11}$ and $Z_{22}$ are skew-Hermitian and $Z_{13}$ and $Z_{24}$ are symmetric.

---

now i am confusing why $Z_{33}$, $Z_{44}$ terms are not needed. 
And again other terms like $Z_{23}$, $Z_{34}$ does not appear.

Am i missing some constraints? From $det(g)=1$ so $tr(Z)=0$, so this terms only related with diagonal terms, but what about others?

It seems that i am missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missed $Z \in sp(p,q)$ is also element in $sp(p+q,\mathbb{C})$

So 
Write 
\begin{align}
  &Z = \begin{pmatrix}
    Z_{11} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} & Z_{14} \\
    Z_{21} &  Z_{22} & Z_{23} & Z_{24} \\
    Z_{31} & Z_{32} & Z_{33} & Z_{34} \\
    Z_{41} & Z_{42} & Z_{43} & Z_{44} 
  \end{pmatrix} 
  = \begin{pmatrix}
    X_1 & Z_2 \\
    X_3 & X_4 
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  & 
  X_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    Z_{11} & Z_{12} \\
    Z_{21} & Z_{22}
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad X_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    Z_{13} & Z_{14} \\
    Z_{23} & Z_{24} 
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad X_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
     Z_{31} & Z_{32} \\
     Z_{41} & Z_{42}
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad X_4 =\begin{pmatrix}
    Z_{33} & Z_{34} \\
    Z_{43} & Z_{44} 
  \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  0 =Z^T K_{p,q} + K_{p,q} \bar{Z}= \begin{pmatrix}
    - \bar{Z}_{11} - Z_{11}^T & - \bar{Z}_{12} + Z_{21}^T & - \bar{Z}_{13} - Z_{31}^T & - \bar{Z}_{14} + Z_{41}^T \\
     - Z_{12}^T + \bar{Z}_{21} & \bar{Z}_{22} + Z_{22}^T & \bar{Z}_{23} - Z_{32}^T & \bar{Z}_{24} + Z_{42}^T \\
      - Z_{13}^T - \bar{Z}_{31} & Z_{23}^T - \bar{Z}_{32} & - \bar{Z}_{33} - Z_{33}^T & - \bar{Z}_{34} + Z_{43}^T \\
      - Z_{14}^T + \bar{Z}_{41} & Z_{24}^T + \bar{Z}_{42} & - Z_{34}^T + \bar{Z}_{43} & \bar{Z}_{44} + Z_{44}^T
  \end{pmatrix} \label{estar}
\end{align}

Want the form
\begin{align}
  Z = \begin{pmatrix}
    Z_{11} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} & Z_{14} \\
    \bar{Z}_{12}^T & Z_{22} & Z_{14}^T & Z_{24} \\
    -\bar{Z}_{13} & \bar{Z}_{14} & \bar{Z}_{11} & -\bar{Z}_{12} \\
    \bar{Z}_{14}^T & -\bar{Z}_{24} & -Z_{12}^T & \bar{Z}_{22} \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
where $Z_{ij}$ are complex matrix. $Z_{11}$ and $Z_{13}$ of order $p$ and $Z_{12}$ and $Z_{14}$ are $p\times q$ matrices. $Z_{11}$ and $Z_{22}$ are skew-Hermitian and $Z_{13}$ and $Z_{24}$ are symmetric.

This can be achieved considering $Z \in sp(p+q,\mathbb{C})$, so 
\begin{align}
  Z = \begin{pmatrix}
    X_1 & X_2  \\
    X_3 & X_4
  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    X_1 & X_2 \\
    X_3 & - X_1^T 
  \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
where $X_2$ and $X_3$ are symmetric.  Thus 
\begin{align}
  & X_4 = - X_1^T   \\
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Z_{33} = -Z_{11}^T = \bar{Z}_{11}  \\
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Z_{34} = - Z_{21}^T = - \bar{Z}_{12}  \\
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Z_{44} = Z_{22}^T = \bar{Z}_{22}  \\
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Z_{43} = -Z_{12}^T \\
  & X_2 = X_2^T  \\
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Z_{13} = Z_{13}^T, \qquad Z_{24} = Z_{24}^T \\
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \quad Z_{13} = - \bar{Z}_{31}^T \quad \Rightarrow \quad Z_{31} = - \bar{Z}_{13}^T = -\bar{Z}_{13}\\
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \quad Z_{24} = - \bar{Z}_{42}^T \quad \Rightarrow \quad Z_{42} = - \bar{Z}_{24}^T = -\bar{Z}_{24} \\ 
  & \qquad \Rightarrow \quad Z_{14} = Z_{23}^T \quad \Rightarrow \quad Z_{23} = Z_{14}^T \\
&   \qquad \textrm{from} \quad Z_{14} = \bar{Z}_{41}^T \quad \Rightarrow \quad Z_{41} = \bar{Z}_{14}^T 
\end{align}
Note in the process we used above constraint, then it provide desired result

Note the traceless condition comes naturally from

\begin{align}
  tr(A+\bar{A})= tr(A) + tr(\bar{A}) = tr(A) + tr(-A^T) = 0 
\end{align}
where $A$ is skew-hermitian matrix